# Convert row to column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider table with schema

```
orders(user int, amount int, created datetime);
```

With one row = transaction, and I want to query the transaction data group by user

e.g.

```
User    First_Order_Amount    First_Order_DateTime Second_OrderAmount    Second_Order_DateTime
1       21                    2019-01-02           22                    2019-01-03
2       13                    2019-01-04           14                    2019-01-05
```

SQL Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v4gZUMFbuYorB27AH9yBKy/8

Comment: what about a "third_order", "seventh_order"... if you are not sure how many orders there might be, rows are better suited to represent your data. (Just a thought)

Comment: Search for mysql rows to columns and mysql pivot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: @GameDroids only 1st, 2nd orders are needed

Comment: @P.Salmon my question is not about pivot table, I only need 1st and 2nd transactions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `MySQL 8+` you can also use `window functions` instead of `group by`:

```
SELECT user, amount, created FROM
(SELECT * ,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY user) AS rn
from orders) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: I simply do not understand how this could be upvoted.  It doesn't even get the first order (and that's only part of what the question is asking).

Comment: I totally missed the horizontal scroll bar, apparently the person who upvoted missed it too. – rad 6 mins ago   Delete

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query for this, e.g.:

```
SELECT o.user,
(SELECT o1.amount FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.user = o.user AND o1.created = (SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders WHERE user = o1.user)) AS first_order_amount,
(SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.user = o.user) AS first_order_datetime, 
(SELECT o1.amount FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.user = o.user AND o1.created = (SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.user = o.user AND o1.created > (SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders WHERE user = o1.user))) AS second_order_amount,
(SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.user = o.user AND o1.created > (SELECT MIN(created) FROM orders WHERE user = o1.user)) AS second_order_datetime
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.user;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/320648/1/0)**.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select o.user,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amount end) as first_order_amount,
        max(case when seqnum = 1 then created end) as first_order_datetime,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amount end) as second_order_amount,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then created end) as second_order_datetime
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by created) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
group by o.user;
```